# Set a property to a non-null value of type 'System.Double'

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I resolve this error?

> The 'CreditsEarned' property on 'Student' could not be set to a 'null'
>   value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type
>   'System.Double'.

Here is my code:

```
public class Student : Person
{
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Enrollment Date")]
    public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }

    // Credits earned
    [Display(Name = "Credits Earned")]
    public double CreditsEarned { get; set; }

    // GPA
    [Display(Name = "GPA")]
    [Range(typeof(double), "0.7", "4.0")]
    public double Gpa { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you using a query or an SP to load one or more students from the database? If so, can you show the query or SP? I'm suspecting that data coming from the database contains a NULL value, and EF cannot transform that data into the entity.

Answer (score 3):

May I ask you why do you want to set an double type to null ?

The double type in C# is not null by default. You must explicitly set it to null.

```
[Display(Name = "Credits Earned")]
public double? CreditsEarned { get; set; }
```

Notice the question mark after the declaration of the type. In C# this tells the compiler that that type might be flagged at nullable.

EDIT:

Please see following links:

1) [Nullable Types in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx)

2) [Nullable Types in C# examples](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/275471/Nullable-Types-in-Csharp-Net)

Comment: statement **You must explicitly set it to null.** is wrong. value types can not be set to null not even explicitly.

Comment: @JenishRabadiya He probably means you explicitly need to specify it to be a `nullable`; if you look at his code, that is what he has done.

Answer (score 0):

you should try

```
// Credits earned
[Display(Name = "Credits Earned")]
public double? CreditsEarned { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Double?` (a ullable of type Double) instead, to allow the property to hold null-values has already been mentioned.

Another option may be to initialize the property to 0, and make sure it is always 0 or some other number.

```
public class Student : Person
{
    // This will make sure the value is initially defined (to 0):
    public Student(){
        CreditsEarned = 0;
    }

    ...

    // Credits earned
    [Display(Name = "Credits Earned")]
    public double CreditsEarned { get; set; }
```